# Kubernetes on Fedora 21 Pod Stays Pending

Tags: docker, kubernetes, fedora-21

I've setup a kubernetes three node cluster using: 
Fedora 21

```
kubernetes-0.7.0-18.0.git52e165a.fc21.x86_64
docker-io-1.4.0-1.fc21.x86_64
```

I created the below pod:

http://dpaste.com/2VSF8XA

Running `kubectl get minions` shows:

```
NAME                LABELS
10.0.0.10           <none>
10.0.0.9            <none>
```

I run `kubectl create -f podfile.json`

Running `kubectl get pod nginxphp` shows:

```
NAME                IMAGE(S)              HOST                LABELS              STATUS
nginxphp            million12/nginx-php   10.0.0.10/          name=nginxphp       Pending
```

Running `kubectl get events` shows:

```
NAME                KIND                STATUS              REASON              MESSAGE
nginxphp            Pod                 Pending             scheduled              Successfully assigned nginxphp to 10.0.0.10
```

The status never gets beyond "Pending"

What are the next steps to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like the pod was scheduled, but never picked up by the minion. Can you include the contents of /var/log/kubelet.log from the kubelet with the 10.0.0.10 IP?  

The [Kubernetes Debugging FAQ](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ) may be able to help as well.

Comment: Log Output: http://dpaste.com/3XDHC4K

Answer (score 1):

Check the first entry here; I suspect your kubelet and apiserver disagree about what your kubelet is called.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ#by-symptom

Comment: This link is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the solution.

```
    +-----------+--------+--------------------------------+
    | Name      | Status | Networks                       |
    +-----------+--------+--------------------------------+
    | kub001    | ACTIVE | private=10.0.0.18, 200.7.6.215 |
    | minion001 | ACTIVE | private=10.0.0.20, 200.7.6.217 |
    | minion002 | ACTIVE | private=10.0.0.19, 200.7.6.216 |
    +-----------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

On the master, in `/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager`, I have:

```
KUBELET_ADDRESSES="--machines=10.0.0.20,10.0.0.19"
```

On minion002, in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet`, I have:

```
KUBELET_HOSTNAME="--hostname_override=10.0.0.19"
```

As long as the above two match, everything is happy, well almost.

The hostnames are bound to the floating external addresses, but cluster traffic is on the internal, private network and that is why **hostname_override** is needed.

It runs, but it still shows as pending on the master when I do `kubectl get events`, I call that progress.

```
NAME                KIND                STATUS              REASON              
nginxphp            Pod                 Pending             scheduled 
nginxphp            Pod                 Pending             scheduled
```

I don't know how to clear out the events from previous attempts, but its working... I think.